# Quickselect's time complexity

Tags: c#, arrays, time-complexity, big-o

I wrote this code to find kth smallest element in the array by renowned algorithm quickselect. Here is [the link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PIqD4L) where you can see the working code.

1. I tested its time complexity by `countFindElement` and `countPartition` together. It is always at most `O(2n)`. But I don't understand why it doesn't yield `O(n²)`. Could you please explain it?
2. Isn't the `Partition` algorithm Haore's?

```
using System.Text.Json;

int []arr = {13,9,8,3,3,4,6,11,3,5};
//int []arr = {157, 38, 97, 17, 148, 23, 108, 111, 1, 196, 74, 4, 40, 143, 119, 108, 15, 169, 108, 157, 58, 87, 135, 14, 127, 132, 141, 124, 142, 34, 142, 141, 113, 86, 86, 153, 125, 150, 160, 194, 182, 57, 189, 180, 18, 192, 111, 150, 123, 88, 192, 126, 13, 97, 200, 188, 96, 85, 168, 23, 60, 3, 56, 168, 130, 169, 161, 20, 160, 63, 90, 5, 52, 85, 90, 139, 125, 119, 109, 112, 73, 40, 85, 62, 177, 160, 194, 128, 184, 102, 123, 87, 20, 52, 184, 17, 102, 193, 67, 169};
//int[] arr = { 158, 481, 313, 277, 16, 495, 94, 109, 272, 255, 374, 9, 79, 205, 179, 386, 242, 315, 223, 250, 465, 257, 289, 405, 347, 390, 496, 386, 430, 121, 352, 75, 251, 376, 169, 492, 355, 341, 208, 391, 171, 382, 331, 471, 358, 478, 25, 336, 304, 84, 487, 178, 258, 3, 410, 324, 180, 468, 275, 456, 97, 407, 433, 441, 176, 148, 350, 121, 275, 461, 122, 350, 180, 337, 494, 284, 414, 352, 52, 89, 464, 105, 94, 328, 306, 404, 457, 325, 10, 346, 177, 276, 68, 250, 440, 266, 163, 233, 191, 412, 291, 198, 320, 171, 141, 243, 278, 399, 205, 77, 342, 402, 53, 456, 374, 36, 389, 293, 453, 458, 25, 56, 40, 127, 278, 330, 93, 250, 185, 293, 243, 22, 377, 0, 217, 171, 130, 308, 365, 440, 175, 9, 493, 283, 264, 63, 365, 485, 429, 353, 479, 286, 190, 290, 25, 336, 203, 462, 236, 340, 279, 311, 118, 449, 357, 93, 139, 471, 393, 279, 88, 51, 280, 446, 368, 330, 390, 10, 494, 388, 406, 33, 420, 86, 236, 109, 183, 247, 157, 154, 462, 215, 40, 428, 374, 330, 85, 263, 363, 224, 143, 43, 394, 15, 431, 355, 1, 225, 246, 249, 430, 151, 68, 432, 284, 294, 442, 126, 216, 416, 500, 377, 440, 416, 169, 310, 15, 417, 178, 136, 411, 127, 77, 358, 460, 146, 409, 357, 341, 497, 151, 255, 245, 306, 342, 257, 119, 302, 386, 278, 124, 493, 315, 491, 150, 174, 204, 85, 97, 240, 240, 240, 382, 173, 3, 166, 460, 413, 65, 122, 275, 183, 144, 142, 344, 283, 366, 129, 107, 98, 410, 282, 228, 465, 39, 455, 144, 2, 139, 444, 407, 154, 132, 376, 385, 348, 30, 213, 366, 72, 227, 243, 496, 57, 315, 420, 257, 244, 187, 194, 60, 365, 345, 389, 286, 424, 493, 188, 270, 423, 16, 336, 228, 196, 355, 427, 288, 109, 124, 200, 143, 248, 219, 343, 203, 347, 345, 469, 327, 128, 481, 16, 357, 110, 37, 447, 417, 107, 489, 468, 490, 434, 86, 383, 245, 159, 472, 382, 1, 251, 268, 354, 49, 138, 124, 275, 184, 172, 499, 133, 150, 177, 381, 306, 122, 232, 77, 64, 186, 105, 363, 486, 209, 213, 351, 285, 420, 148, 499, 448, 438, 131, 469, 239, 446, 440, 484, 455, 81, 68};

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(arr));
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length + 1; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1} smallest => " + FindKthElem(arr, i + 1));
}

/*
 2) How is it NOT "O(n^2)"? It is almost "O(2n)"? How?
 
 It finds k-th smallest element(k) in the given array, arr
 l left index
 r right index
 */
int FindKthElem(int[] arr, int k)
{
    int countFindElement = 0;
    int countPartition = 0;
    if (k > arr.Length) return -1;
    int r = arr.Length - 1;
    int l = 0;
    while (l <= r)
    {
        countFindElement++;
        // O(n)
        int pivotIndex = Partition(arr, l, r, out countPartition);
        countFindElement += countPartition;
        int nthElement = arr[pivotIndex];
        if (k - 1 == pivotIndex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("how many " + countFindElement);
            return nthElement;
        }
        else if (k - 1 > pivotIndex)
        {
            l = pivotIndex + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            r = pivotIndex - 1;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("how many " + countFindElement);
    return -1;
}

/*
 1) It is haore partition -- Isn't it?
 
 I hide pivot element always at rightmost.
 It places smaller or equal elements than pivot to that of left-side
 It places greater elements than pivot to that of right-side
 */
int Partition(int[] a, int l, int r, out int count)
{
    int c = 0;
    int pIndex = r;
    int p = a[pIndex];
    r--;
    while(l <= r)
    {
        c++;
        while (l < pIndex && a[l] <= p)
        {
            l++;
        }
        while (r >= 0 && a[r] > p)
        {
            r--;
        }

        if (l < r)
        {
            (a[l], a[r]) = (a[r], a[l]);
            l++;
            r--;
        }
    }
    (a[l], a[pIndex]) = (a[pIndex], a[l]);
    count = c;
    return l;
}
```

The output

```
[13,9,8,3,3,4,6,11,3,5]
how many 10
1 smallest => 3
how many 12
2 smallest => 3
how many 12
3 smallest => 3
how many 12
4 smallest => 4
how many 12
5 smallest => 5
how many 10
6 smallest => 6
how many 8
7 smallest => 8
how many 6
8 smallest => 9
how many 4
9 smallest => 11
how many 2
10 smallest => 13
11 smallest => -1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Even in the worst case the range `l,r` passed into the `Partition` method narrows down by 1 everytime:

   ```
   0 ~ n-1
   1 ~ n-1
   ...
   n-1 ~ n-1
   ```

   So the maximum number of cycles is `(0 + n-1) * n / 2`, it should be considered as `O(n²)`.

   There're 2 problems in your question:

   1.1 Count the number of cycles in the innermost loop:

   ```
     //countFindElement++;

     ....

     //c++;
     while (l <= r && a[l] <= p)
     {
         l++;
         c++;
     }
     while (r > l && a[r] > p)
     {
         r--;
         c++;
     }
   ```

   1.2 Since elements before `l` are not bigger than `p` and elements after `r` are bigger than `p`, therefore there is still room for optimization in the bounds inside the `Partition` method. (code above)

   1.3 Array is reference type in C#, you should clone it everytime.

   ```
     FindKthElem((int[])arr.Clone(), i + 1)
   ```
2. No, the name of the inventor is Tony Hoare, not Haore ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, a thing I don't understand actually the [actual quickselect](https://afteracademy.com/images/find-kth-smallest-comparison1.png) is of O(n) time complexity. Why is that in question of O(n^2)? Is the problem due to my `Partition` algorithm? Why couldn't I get it in O(n)?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. There's no much problem with your code, though I added a new one (see 1.2), `O(n)` is the average complexity, the worst complexity is `O(n²)`. There's no such time complexity as `O(2n)`, it is also regarded as `O(n)`, it indicates that time increases linearly with `n`.